# how to make play/stop button for 2 radio stream on the same page?

Tags: jquery, audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I made 2 buttons for my radio streams, each one act like a PLAY/STOP button.

1. play/stop for stream 1 (shoutcast or icecast)
2. play/stop for stream 2 (shoutcast or icecast)

This is what i did, hen you press on both buttons, only 1 stream (funk) is played, the second one is not playing at all (disco)

can you help me please?
thank you
Tony

```js
var player1 = document.querySelector('audio');
var player2 = document.querySelector('audio');
var playBtn1 = document.querySelector('#play-btn_funk');
var playBtn2 = document.querySelector('#play-btn_disco');


playBtn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
 if ( player1.paused ) {
  player1.play();
  playBtn1.src = 'img/stop_funk.png';
 } else {
  player1.pause();
  playBtn1.src = 'img/play_funk.png';
 }
});

playBtn2.addEventListener('click', function() {
 if ( player2.paused ) {
  player2.play();
  playBtn2.src = 'img/stop_disco.png';
 } else {
  player2.pause();
  playBtn2.src = 'img/play_disco.png';
 }
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family:monospace;
 margin:0;
 line-height:1.45;
}

* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

#container_funk {
    float: left;
 width: 100px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding: 1em;
 margin-top:5px;
}

#play-btn_funk {
 width:100px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display:inline-block;
}

#container_disco {
 position:relative;
    float:left;
 width: 100px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding: 1em;
 margin-top:5px;
}

#play-btn_disco {
 width:100px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>HTML5 Audio Player</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container_funk">
  <audio id="funk">
  <source type="audio/mpeg" src="http://163.172.29.170:8000/;"/>
  </audio>
  <img id="play-btn_funk" src="img/play_funk.png" />
  </div>
<div id="container_disco">
  <audio id="disco">
  <source type="audio/mpeg" src="http://163.172.29.170:8080/;"/>
 </audio>
 <img id="play-btn_disco" src="img/play_disco.png" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/audio.js"></script></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good already. It just needs a minor tweak.

The `player1` and `player2` variables reference exactly the same `<audio/>` element. `document.querySelector()` will search the DOM for the first matching element which is `#funk` in your case. Just replace the first two lines with an explicit query for each player.

```
var player1 = document.querySelector('#funk');
var player2 = document.querySelector('#disco');
```

Comment: I think this is the official guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ... but it looks like you already figured it out. :-)